# Is it valid to use a <div> inside a <label>?

Tags: css, html

I've a `label` element whose contents needs some styling. This label can't be adjusted, so it would be handy to use a `<div>` or block-level elements inside the label. So I'm wondering if it is valid to use a `<div>` in a `<label>` in HTML5.

Answer (score 7):

[the label element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element):

> Content model:
>   Phrasing content, but with no descendant labelable elements unless it is the element's labeled control, and no descendant label elements.

[phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1):

> a abbr area (if it is a descendant of a map element) audio b bdi bdo br button canvas cite code data datalist del dfn em embed i iframe img input ins kbd keygen label map mark math meter noscript object output progress q ruby s samp script select small span strong sub sup svg template textarea time u var video wbr text

---

So no. Div elements may not be descendants of labels.

Comment: Thanks, and what about using a `<span>` which I turn into `display: block`. Guess this won't be valid as well?

Comment: The value of the display property has no bearing on the validity of the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Use the span element. I drew up a simple example here:

```
<label for="">click me <span>span</span> </label>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hukxyxfq/1/

Comment: Thought of this as well, but what if I need to put on some margin/padding?  Then I need something like display:block. Is it still valid then?

Comment: You could make it display: block...please give more example code, don't just give hypotheticals.